# MySQL update column values with select using substring locate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table named `cea_no` and the sample data is like this `"CEA: R017722B / L3009740K"`.
I want to update the column values by like this `R017722B` only. I already have a query that cuts or trims the values to this `"CEA: R017722B /` by using this query:

```
select cea_no, substring(cea_no, 1, locate('/', cea_no)) as x from xp_guru_listings
```

```
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
| id | cea_no                      | x                |
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
|  1 | "CEA: R017722B / L3009740K" | "CEA: R017722B / |
|  2 | "CEA: R016023J / L3009793I" | "CEA: R016023J / |
|  3 | "CEA: R011571E / L3002382K" | "CEA: R011571E / |
|  4 | "CEA: R054044J / L3010738A" | "CEA: R054044J / |
|  5 | "CEA: R041180B / L3009250K" | "CEA: R041180B / |
|  6 | "CEA: R030152G / L3008022J" | "CEA: R030152G / |
|  7 | "CEA: R057318G / L3008022J" | "CEA: R057318G / |
|  8 | "CEA: R043256G / L3002382K" | "CEA: R043256G / |
|  9 | "CEA: R026068E / L3002382K" | "CEA: R026068E / |
| 10 | "CEA: R053784I / L3008022J" | "CEA: R053784I / |
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

Question: how can I update every row with that value. I already tried this

```
UPDATE xp_guru_listings set  cea_no = (select substring(cea_no, 1, locate('/', cea_no)))
from xp_guru_listings;
```

It says syntax error. Can someone tell me what should I do? Thanks.

Error code:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from xp_guru_listings' at line 2

Comment: please post the complete error message and things will go much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below if every value in the cea column contains / (slash) character

```
UPDATE xp_guru_listings set cea_no = substring(cea_no, 1, locate('/', cea_no))
from xp_guru_listings;
```

Comment: UPDATE xp_guru_listings set cea_no = substring(cea_no, 1, locate('/', cea_no));

Comment: please use the above. we need to remove from clause from the above statement

Comment: okay it works. thanks. why it does give me an error when i put where clause?

Comment: great.. Sub query is returning more than 1 record. So it is failing to update one row

Comment: how could take or update all rows by`R053784I` instead of `"CEA: R053784I /`